# Vue 3 Reaching through components uses wrong function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I've got the following problem, while reading in a File and reaching it to the Parent Component.

First I've got an FileInput on the FileReaderComponent, when File is Changed it sends an `emit('change', file.content)`.
The top Component gets the file.content and sets it as the Input Prop of the FileViewerComponent.
As so far, it works as expected. But when I add a second FileReaderComponent, which Content should be displayed in the second FileViewerComponent.
But it always uses the @change from the first FileReaderComponent.

I'm very new to Vue. I build an minimal example to show:
Same behavior. When I use the Second FileReaderComponent it should put data into readerOutput2 but it puts data into readerOutput1 for some reason.

I can't figure out what I did wrong.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <!-- <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/lpdLogo.svg" style="width: 100px; fill: green;"> -->
  <FileReaderComponent @change="data.readerOutput1 = $event"/>
  <FileViewerComponent v-model:input="data.readerOutput1"/>
  <FileReaderComponent @change="data.readerOutput2 = $event"/>
  <FileViewerComponent v-model:input="data.readerOutput2"/>
</template>

<script>
import FileReaderComponent from './components/FileReaderComponent.vue';
import FileViewerComponent from './components/FileViewerComponent.vue';
import { reactive } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    FileReaderComponent,
    FileViewerComponent
  },
  setup () {
    const data = reactive({
      readerOutput1: '',
      readerOutput2: ''
    });
    
    function log(toLog) {
      console.log(toLog);
    }

    return { log, data }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

**FileReaderComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="fileUploadComponent" class="inline-flex items-center p-2 rounded border-2 border-yellow-500 m-1">
    <input type='file' id="fileInput" name="fileInput" @change="fileUploadChange()" ref="fileInput" class="hidden"/>
    <label for="fileInput" class="h-10 w-40 rounded text-gray-300 dark:text-gray-400 bg-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-500 text-xs" style="line-height: 2.5rem">
       <span class="block text-center w-full">Datei öffnen</span></label>
     <span id="filenamefield" class="inline-block m-2 text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300">{{file.name}}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {reactive} from 'vue';
export default {
  name: 'FileReaderComponent',
  emits: ['inFocus', 'submit', 'change'],
  props: {
    input: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    }, 
  },
  methods : {
      setContent(content) {
        console.log('FileUpload, set Content', content)
        this.file.content = content;
        this.$emit('change', content);
    },
    fileUploadChange() {
        console.log('fileUploadChange triggered');
        this.file.input = this.$refs.fileInput.files[0];
        this.file.name = this.file.input.name;
        let file = this.file.input;

        let parent = this;
        parent.setContent('Content Loading')
        function onloadevent(evt) {
            parent.setContent(evt.target.result);
        }

        if (file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
          reader.onload = function (evt) {
              onloadevent(evt);
          }
          reader.onerror = function () {
              onloadevent('An Error occurred while reading File');
          }
        }
    }
  },
  setup(props, {emit}) {
      const file = reactive({
          name: 'Keine Ausgewählt',
          input: Element,
          content: String,
      })

      return {file}
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>
    .inputfile {
        width: 0.1px;
        height: 0.1px;
        opacity: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .inputfile+label {
        font-weight: 700;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    input:checked+svg {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

**FileViewerComponent**

```
<template>
  <div id="fileViewerComponent" class="inline-flex items-center p-2 rounded border-2 border-yellow-500 m-1">
      <h3>Input:</h3>
    <div id="view">
        {{ input }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {reactive} from 'vue';
export default {
  name: 'FileViewerComponent',
  emits: ['inFocus', 'submit', 'change'],
  props: {
    input: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    }, 
  },
  methods : {

  },
  setup(props, {emit}) {
      const file = reactive({
          name: 'Keine Ausgewählt',
          input: Element,
          content: String,
      })

      return {file}
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: I just rebuilt your code example [at the Vue SFC Playground: tinyurl.com/kscn7fn3 - it seems to work as expected? I can see the file content below each corresponding file input!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the Problem. The label for the FileInput is pointing to id="fileInput" and uses the first found input on click. You can test this in SFC Playground by clicking the label next to the second FileInput.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got an Solution.
The Problem was caused by the FileInput label pointing to id="fileInput" wich is the input. But when the input is 2 times rendered, the label accesses the first found id="fileInput".

My Solution:

**FileUploadComponent.vue**

I had to reach an ID to the Component an use it for the Input ID and the label for

```
<template>
  <div id="fileUploadComponent" class="inline-flex items-center p-2 rounded border-2 border-yellow-500 m-1">
    <input type='file' v-bind:id="id" name="fileInput" @change="fileUploadChange()" ref="fileInput" class="hidden"/>
    <label v-bind:for="id" class="h-10 w-40 rounded text-gray-300 dark:text-gray-400 bg-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-500 text-xs" style="line-height: 2.5rem">
       <span class="block text-center w-full">Datei öffnen</span></label>
     <span id="filenamefield" class="inline-block m-2 text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300">{{file.name}}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {reactive} from 'vue';
export default {
  name: 'FileReaderComponent',
  emits: ['inFocus', 'submit', 'change'],
  props: {
    input: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    id : {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    } 
  },
  methods : {
      setContent(content) {
        console.log('FileUpload, set Content', content)
        this.file.content = content;
        this.$emit('change', content);
    },
    fileUploadChange() {
        console.log('fileUploadChange triggered');
        this.file.input = this.$refs.fileInput.files[0];
        this.file.name = this.file.input.name;
        let file = this.file.input;

        let parent = this;
        parent.setContent('Content Loading')
        function onloadevent(evt) {
            parent.setContent(evt.target.result);
        }

        if (file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
          reader.onload = function (evt) {
              onloadevent(evt);
          }
          reader.onerror = function () {
              onloadevent('An Error occurred while reading File');
          }
        }
    }
  },
  setup(props, {emit}) {
      const file = reactive({
          name: 'Keine Ausgewählt',
          input: Element,
          content: String,
      })

      return {file}
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>
    .inputfile {
        width: 0.1px;
        height: 0.1px;
        opacity: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .inputfile+label {
        font-weight: 700;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    input:checked+svg {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```